# SQL Snippets on DBA.SE?

Tags: feature-request

[Stack Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) arrived on SO last September and they are great - I love [this demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269862/533832) which shows off what you can do with them.

They basically bring a subset of JSFiddle into the site, and something similar could be done with a subset of SQLFiddle here.

To see what I'm proposing, please go to **[this SQL-only answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35398/1396)** on a postgres question (please vote up Erwin's excellent effort there when you pass by!), and run this script on the console (only tested on Firefox):

```
$('div.post-text>blockquote').each(function(){ 
  $(this).css('background-color','#dde');
  $('<input type="button" value="edit">').appendTo(this).click(function(){
     $(this).closest('blockquote').children('pre').filter(function(){ return /^[^/]/.test($(this).text()); }).each(function(){
       $('<textarea style="height: 8px; width: 100%; resize: none; box-sizing: border-box; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;" wrap="off" name="sql[]">'+$(this).text()+'</textarea>').replaceAll($(this))
         .keyup(function(){
           var st = $(window).scrollTop();
           $(this).css("height", "").css("height", this.scrollHeight);
           $(window).scrollTop(st);
         }).keyup();
     });
     $('<input type="button" value="run">').replaceAll($(this)).click(function(){
       var textareas = $(this).closest('blockquote').find('textarea[name^=sql]');
       $.ajax({ dataType: "json", type: 'POST'
              ,      url: 'http://fiddle.douglastechnology.co.uk'
              ,     data: textareas.serialize() }).done(function(r){
         r.output.forEach(function(e,i){
           if(e.hasOwnProperty('result')){
             textareas.eq(i).next().children('code').children('span').text('/*\n'+e.result+'\n*/');
           }
         });
       });
     });
  });
})
```

If it works, you should find an 'edit' button appears:

[image: With 'edit' button]

Pressing 'edit' allows you to change the SQL:

[image]

Here's what I get after changing the `limit` in the query to `3` and pressing 'run':

[image]

Do we want this on DBA.SE? This is just a rough and ready proof of principle - I'm imagining something more like the actual Stack Snippets interface on SO with a pop-up editor.

Comment: Works on Chrome version 39.0.2171.95 m

Comment: That's good to know, thanks for checking. Seems to work in IE11 too somewhat to my surprise...

Comment: worked on chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m for me while behind a corporate firewall but a bit slow to load. Specifically it took over ten seconds for the initial page to load and over five seconds for the results to appear after pressing run

Comment: @kevinsky Thanks. When you say ten seconds for the page to load, you mean just for the normal link before the js is run? Do you get the same issue on other DBA.SE pages?

Comment: @JackDouglas all SE pages load like greased lightning.  When I click on this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0af9c/12 it takes over ten seconds to load, the ads at the bottom load right away, and then over three trials the actual fiddle takes 20 to thirty seconds to load. My Location Ottawa,Ontario

Comment: @kevinsky I've removed the SQLFiddle link to prevent confusion - it's not directly related to this post. Does the 'SQL Snippet' work for you?

Comment: Pretty slick. Response was pretty good too.

Comment: Why isn't this feature-request considered ? I'd really like it to happen

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure because I don't think I had any response — but my guess is that it's too much effort here. It'd be useful for the SQL tag on SO as well though…